# ArangoDB modify collection properties (keyOptions)

Tags: curl, collections, arangodb

I have arangoDB already running with some collections filled with documents. I let arangoDB set up the `_key` for each document (traditional type).

I just found out that there is another type of setting up the `_key`, so called incremental type, which for me would be a high improvement of the DB as the `_key` values I am getting now are too long.

I know I can modify properties for already existing collections (see [ArangoDB documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/Manual/HttpCollection/Modifying.html)). However when I try to modify `keyOptions` *(see code below)*, `keyOptions` remains as type `"traditional"`.

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @- --dump - http://localhost:8529/_db/mydb/_api/collection/companies/properties <<EOF
{
    "keyOptions": {"increment": 1, "type": "autoincrement"}
}
EOF
```

In [ArangoDB documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.8/Manual/HttpCollection/Modifying.html) they specify:  *Note: some other collection properties, such as type, isVolatile,
numberOfShards or shardKeys cannot be changed once a collection is
created*.

So I understand that `keyOptions` should be able to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only attributes of a collection that you can change are `waitForSync` and `journalSize`. That is also what the documentation says.

The note (*Note: some other collection properties, such as type, isVolatile, numberOfShards or shardKeys cannot be changed once a collection is created.*) in the documentation is a little misleading. It only list a few examples of non modifiable attributes.

In summary: keyOptions is not be able to modify.

Comment: Clarified in the docs: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/7b21fe309f9e1329a63b43e18501b15f1632ba0d